# Prove that a recursive sequence converges and determine its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I've been working on this task for hours now but I just can't prove that this recursive sequence is convergent.

$$
a_0=5 \\
a_{n+1}=\frac15(2+6a_n-{a_n}^2)
$$

Feeding some values to the calculator, one can clearly see that this sequence converges to 2. I firstly wanted to show that the sequence is monotone, however when I try doing something like that:

$$
a_{n+1} \geq a_n
$$
I end up at: $$ -1 \leq a_n \leq 2$$
which just confuses me even more.

How can I show that this recursive sequence converges to 2?

Thanks very much in advance to all who try to help me.

**Edit:**

As stated in some comments below, I just need to show additionally that $ a_{n+1} \leq 2 $. But when I plug in the $ a_{n+1} $ from above I get $ \frac15(2+6a_n-{a_n}^2) \leq 2 $ what leaves me stuck again.

Comment: Well, from the second term on it appears to be monotone increasing and bounded above by $2$.   I'd start by proving that.  That would prove that it converges and from there it is easy to prove that it converges to $2$.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the statement that $-1 \leq a_n \leq 2$ as it's certainly true for $n \geq 1$ so if you've proven that you've reached a reasonable conclusion.

Comment: Studying the variation of $f(x)=\frac{1}{5}(2+6x-x^2)$ and $f(x)-x)$ can solve all you problem. Because $2$ is a fix point of $f$

Comment: @lulu so when I use my result for $ a_{n+1} \geq a_n $ and show that it is bounded from above by 2 for $ n \geq 1 $ this would show that it converges to 2, but how do i prove that 2 is a upper bound?

Comment: As I say, you need to prove $\textit {two}$ things in the induction.  First that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ and second that $a_{n+1}<2$.

Answer (score 1):

So taking

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{5}(2+6x-x^2)$$

$f$ is two order polynomial with a maxima at $x=3$ equal to $\dfrac{11}{5}$

So $a_n$ is minored by $\dfrac{11}{5}$.

Secondly:

$$f(x)-x=\frac{1}{5}(2+x-x^2)$$

which admit minima at $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$ equal to $\dfrac{9}{20}$

---

So because $a_{n+1}-a_n=f(x_n)-x_n>0$

$a_n$ growths. It is further majorated by $\dfrac{11}{5}$ (show it from $a_1$ by iteration)

Thus the limit if the positive fix point of $f$ (because $a_n$ is positive) which is at $f(x)-x=0$ i.e $x=2$

Hence we get: **$$a_n \rightarrow 2$$**

Answer (score 0):

Define $e_n=a_n-2$, therefore$$e_{n+1}={1\over5}(2+6a_n-a_n^2)-2={1\over5}(6a_n-a_n^2-8)=-{a_n-4\over 5}({a_n-2})=-{a_n-4\over 5}e_n$$hence $$|e_{n+1}|=|{a_n-4\over 5}||e_n|\le {2\over 5}|e_n|$$which leads to $e_n\to 0$ or $a_n\to 2$ since for all $n>1$, $2<a_{n+1}<a_{n}$.